# evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am interested in evaluating the following limit:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}$$
I realize it should be 3 because as $n$ approaches infinity, $3^n$ gets significantly larger than $2^n$.
But numerically:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n+3^n}{1}}=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(\frac{2}{3})^n+1}{\frac{1}{3^n}}}$$
which is $\sqrt[\infty]{\frac{2}{0}}$ ..?
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Denominator $( (1/3)^n)^{1/n}=1/3$ $\not=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Note that $$3=\sqrt[n]{3^n}<\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}<\sqrt[n]{2\cdot 3^n}=3\cdot 2^{1\over n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$\sqrt[n]{2^n+3^n}=\sqrt[n]{3^n\left(1+(\tfrac23)^n\right)} =3\cdot \sqrt[n]{1+(\tfrac23)^n}$$
instead.